# How to convert random domain names into lowercase consistent urls?

Tags: php, regex, oop, url

I have this function in a class:

```
protected $supportedWebsitesUrls = ['www.youtube.com', 'www.vimeo.com', 'www.dailymotion.com'];

protected function isValid($videoUrl)
{
    $urlDetails = parse_url($videoUrl);

    if (in_array($urlDetails['host'], $this->supportedWebsitesUrls))
    {
        return true;
    } else {
        throw new \Exception('This website is not supported yet!');

        return false;
    }

}
```

It basically extracts the host name from any random url and then checks if it is in the `$supportedWebsitesUrls` array to ensure that it is from a supported website. But if I add say: `dailymotion.com` instead of `www.dailymotion.com` it won't detect that url. Also if I try to do WWW.DAILYMOTION.COM it still won't work. What can be done? Please help me.

Comment: For `WWW.DAILYMOTION.COM` you can use `in_array(strtolower($urlDetails['host']), $this->supportedWebsitesUrls)`

Comment: @Uchiha Thanks one down, two to go!

Comment: @Homo Sapien so what does not work yet?

Comment: if(strpos(...) ===0)) str_replace() or preg_replace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [preg_grep function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) for this. `preg_grep` supports regex matches against a given array.

**Sample use:**

```
$supportedWebsitesUrls = array('www.dailymotion.com', 'www.youtube.com', 'www.vimeo.com');

$s = 'DAILYMOTION.COM';

if ( empty(preg_grep('/' . preg_quote($s, '/') . '/i', $supportedWebsitesUrls)) )
   echo 'This website is not supported yet!\n';
else
   echo "found a match\n";
```

**Output:**

```
found a match
```

Comment: This would be a more efficient way of doing this than my answer. Suggest going with this for your final implimentation.

Comment: You're very welcome - I am actually glad I found this answer personally as while I wasnt looking for a more efficient way for a similiar function, I found it here. so thanks anubhava!

Comment: What is meant by /i what type of regex is it?

Comment: `/i` is for **ignore case** match

Answer (score 1):

You can run a few checks on it;

For lower case vs upper case, the php function [`strtolower()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) will sort you out.

as for checking with the **www.** at the beginning vs without it, you can add an extra check to your if clause;

```
if (in_array($urlDetails['host'], $this->supportedWebsitesUrls) || in_array('www.'.$urlDetails['host'], $this->supportedWebsitesUrls))
```